# Serialise selective class variables in Java

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I need to serialize some fields depending on condition.

For example, I have the following class.

```
public class ClassExample
{
  private String id;
  private String type;
  private String string_1;
  private String string_2;
}
```

So, assuming that type can receive two values, 'type_1' or 'type_2' and that string_1 and string_2 will always be null (they will be changed by another application).

I want to serialize that using Jackson, and I want to:

1) In case it is type_1, string_1 shows up in the JSON and string_2 not.

2) In case it is type_2, string_2 shows up in the JSON and string_1 not.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd need a custom serializer for this, but the data structure itself sounds a bit messy although I don't have much context about your application

Comment: I simplified a lot because I can't put much information about the application, so sorry about that. So, the only way is with a custom serializer?

Comment: Yes it's not a standard behaviour, so you won't get it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The nullability of a field depending on another one is probably a sign that you should split your classes in 2. Instead of a type field with 2 possible values you can replace this one by 2 classes without any type field inside.
And so no need for custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand you want to serialize class fields that meet a criteria.
There are multiple ways to solve this, as you want the solution without a using Custom serializer, here's a solve:-

The solution is based on FilterProvider of Jackson.

**Suggestions:-**

1. Use Custom Serialiser, use the solution mentioned if you have very hard constraints
2. Please Make type as Enum and have a different implementation on the basis of type actions accordingly.

**If you can elaborate on your use case, I can recommend a better solution.**

Solution:-

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.PropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.PropertyWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Getter
@Setter
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class ClassExample {
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String string_1;
    private String string_2;
    private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final PropertyFilter theFilter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
        @Override
        public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen,
                                     SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer)
                throws Exception {
            if (include(writer)) {
                if (!(writer.getName().equals("string_1") || writer.getName().equals("string_2"))) {
                    writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                    return;
                }

                String type = ((ClassExample) pojo).getType();
                if ("type_1".equals(type) && (writer.getName().equals("string_1"))) {
                    writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                } else if ("type_2".equals(type) && (writer.getName().equals("string_2"))) {
                    writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                }

            } else if (!jgen.canOmitFields()) { // since 2.3
                writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    public String toString() {
        try {

            FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter", theFilter);
            return om.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error while serialisation", e);
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new ClassExample("123", "type_1", "1", "2"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
If type is type_1 then {"id":"123","type":"type_1","string_1":"1"}
If type if type_2 then {"id":"123","type":"type_2","string_2":"2"}
```

Comment: I agree with you @CodeScale there are a lot of better ways to solve this but from the question and the comments I thought he wants this kind of solution because of certain constraints.